# Flutter has event before entering the router?

Tags: flutter

I want to determine if the user is logged in before entering the route, so I want to know if there has event or interceptor before entering every routers.

Answer (score 0):

in `StatefulWidget`'s you can check in the `initState` method this

> initState : Called when this object is inserted into the tree.
>
> The framework will call this method exactly once for each [State] object it creates.

if you'r using `FirebaseAuth` you can check in `initState` like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      if (user == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        // you can navigate back if there is a no user
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```